# Recaptcha with Devise in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, recaptcha

I am using devise as an authentication solution for my rails4 app and want to use recaptcha when user signs up but don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the directions here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-Recaptcha-with-Devise

1. Get your keys from Google/Recaptcha
2. Install the Recaptcha gem found
   here (note: for Rails 3 do gem 'recaptcha', :require =>
   'recaptcha/rails')
3. Add <%= recaptcha_tags %> on your New
   Registration view (you must have generated Devise views) the line
   before your submit button.
4. Create/Update your
   RegistrationsController - see the "controllers" section in the
   README to understand how to set up your own devise controllers. Remember that "devise" expects you to use flash[:notice] and flash[:alert] and not flash[:error].
5. Don't forget to update the routes once you do.